# Tmux unbinding ctrl-b not working

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I am trying to unbind <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and instead bind the prefix to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.

Though, I am not too sure if my TMUX settings are correctly configured (or connected for that matter). When I began trying to mess with TMUX, I couldn't find the file, so I followed some advice on SO and typed:

```
tmux show -g | cat > ~/.tmux.conf
```

And now in my ~/.tmux.conf it looks like this

```
lock-server on
message-command-style fg=yellow,bg=black
message-style fg=black,bg=yellow
mouse-resize-pane off
mouse-select-pane off
lock-command "lock -np"
lock-server on
message-command-style fg=yellow,bg=black
message-style fg=black,bg=yellow
mouse-resize-pane off
mouse-select-pane off
mouse-select-window off
mouse-utf8 on
prefix C-b
prefix2 none
renumber-windows off
repeat-time 500
set-remain-on-exit off
set-titles off
set-titles-string "#S:#I:#W - "#T""
status on
status-interval 15
status-justify left
status-keys emacs
status-left "[#S] "
status-left-length 10
status-left-style default
status-position bottom
status-right " "#{=21:pane_title}" %H:%M %d-%b-%y"
status-right-length 40
status-right-style default
status-style fg=black,bg=green
status-utf8 on
update-environment "DISPLAY SSH_ASKPASS SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_CONNECTION WINDOWID XAUTHORITY"
visual-activity off
visual-bell off
visual-silence off
word-separators " -_@"
set -g status-keys vi
setw -g mode-keys vi
set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind C-a send-prefix
~
lock-command "lock -np"
lock-server on
message-command-style fg=yellow,bg=black
message-style fg=black,bg=yellow
mouse-resize-pane off
mouse-select-pane off
mouse-select-window off
mouse-utf8 on
prefix C-b
prefix2 none
renumber-windows off
repeat-time 500
set-remain-on-exit off
set-titles off
set-titles-string "#S:#I:#W - "#T""
status on
status-interval 15
status-justify left
status-keys emacs
status-left "[#S] "
status-left-length 10
status-left-style default
status-position bottom
status-right " "#{=21:pane_title}" %H:%M %d-%b-%y"
status-right-length 40
status-right-style default
status-style fg=black,bg=green
status-utf8 on
update-environment "DISPLAY SSH_ASKPASS SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_CONNECTION WINDOWID XAUTHORITY"
visual-activity off
visual-bell off
visual-silence off
word-separators " -_@"
set -g status-keys vi
setw -g mode-keys vi
set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind C-a send-prefix
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does Ctrl-B still work, then? Also, I wouldn’t trust any advice that included `| cat >`. Remove everything from your `.tmux.conf` except for the binding and see what happens.

Comment: Ctrl-B still works. I'll try that now.

Comment: Hm, I guess all that stuff was making it not work. Thanks. I wonder why that was.